# Adding numbers of a field

Tags: awk

I am having a text file with multiple rows and two or four column. If two column then  1st column is id and 2nd is number and if four column 1st and 2nd is id and 3rd and 4th is number. For the four column rows 2nd and 4th column cells can have multiple entry separated by comma. If there is two column only I want to print them as it is; but if there is four column I want to print only the 1st column id and in the second column I want the sum of all the number present in 3rd and 4th column for that row.

## Input

```
    CG  AT,AA,CA    17  1,1,1
    GT  14
    TB  AC,TC,TA,GG,TT,AR,NN,NM,AB,AT,TT,TC,CA,BB,GT,AT,XT,MT,NA,TT         552 6,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,5,3,4,1,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,4
    TT  CG,GT,TA,GB 105 3,4,1,3
```

## Expected Output

```
    CG  20
    GT  14
    TB  602
    TT  116
```

Comment: I love how much this resembles first year comp. science homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution coded to follow your instruction as closely as possible (with no field-splitting tricks so that it's easy to reason about):

```
awk '
    NF == 2 {
        print $1, $2
        next
    }
    NF == 4 {
        N = split($4, f, /,/)
        for (i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
            $3 += f[i]
        print $1, $3
    }'
```

I noticed though that your input section contains leading spaces. If leading spaces are actually present (and are irrelevant), we can add a leading `{ sub(/^ +/, "") }` to the script.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no leading spaces in the actual file, use `$1` instead of `$2`.

```
$ awk -F '[ ,]+' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) s+=$i; print $2, s; s=0}' <<EOF
    CG  AT,AA,CA    17  1,1,1
    GT  14
    TB  AC,TC,TA,GG,TT,AR,NN,NM,AB,AT,TT,TC,CA,BB,GT,AT,XT,MT,NA,TT         552 6,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,5,3,4,1,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,4
    TT  CG,GT,TA,GB 105 3,4,1,3
EOF

CG 20
GT 14
TB 602
TT 116
```

- `-F '[ ,]+'` means "fields are delimited by one or more spaces or commas".
- There is no condition associated with the `{action}`, so it will be performed on every line.
- `NF` is the Number of Fields, and `$X` refers to the Xth field.
- Strings are equal to 0, so we can simply add every field together to get a sum.
- After we print the first non-blank field and our sum, we reset the sum for the next line.